# React Native select default value to 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I hope you all can help me with this problem, I just want that if the selection is no value, the it will automatic 1, and if not, it will get the value of what the user select in the dropdown (I dont have problem with that), My problem is, I just want that if the user dont select in the dropdown menu, it will get automatic 1.

```
const submitForm = async(valuesToSubmit) => 
{
 console.log("valuesToSubmit:= ", valuesToSubmit['documentId'])
 let _intfmdocument=0,
 if valuesToSubmit['documentId'] !== null{
    _intfmdocument = valuesToSubmit['documentId']
 }else{
    _intfmdocument = 1
 }
 .....

}



<Select 
   isSearchable
   options={docuLoc}
   className={classes.selection}
   value={documentId!== null ? documentId: 1}
   onChange={(itemValue) => {
          setDisplaySelectedDocumentLocation(itemValue)
          setFieldValue("documentLocationsId",itemValue.value)
   }}
   name='documentId'
 />
```

this is the result of **console.log("valuesToSubmit:= ", valuesToSubmit['documentId'])**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you really just need to set a default value

Tray adding:

`defaultValue={{ label: "whatever the label is", value: 1 }}`

somewhere to the  attributes